# Change column name with matching string from list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Hello  i have  one  pandas datafrmae and a list

my data  frame

```
xy_123        ba_322         ab_321      zx_223

  1            1                1           1 

  s2           f32             r32          s223
```

list=   [  "xy_123_8.4",   "ba_322_9.5",  "ab_321_8.4",  "zx_223_9.5"]

output i am looking at

```
xy_123_8.4        ba_322_9.5        ab_321_8.4     zx_223_9.5

       1            1                1           1 

       s2           f32             r32          s223
```

I have large dataframe  want to change column name is there any posibility do from  python pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rename` by dictionary:

```
L =  [ "xy_123_8.4", "ba_322_9.5", "ab_321_8.4", "zx_223_9.5"]

d = {x.rsplit('_', 1)[0]:x for x in L}

df = df.rename(columns=d)
print (df)
  xy_123_8.4 ba_322_9.5 ab_321_8.4 zx_223_9.5
0          1          1          1          1
1         s2        f32        r32       s223
```

Comment: Thank you so much worked fine , same how can change row names

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not to use list as a variable name. in your case

```
df.columns = list
```